# GF Wonton/Dumpling wrapper tip from pintrest (lasagna noodle + egg)

Tags: gluten-free, dumplings

I bought gluten-free lasagna noodles, but I'm at a loss for how they want me to fold them. They are *hard* pasta noodles. Do I whisk a whole egg up to brush them? Just egg whites? Just egg yolks? Am I supposed to par-boil them to soften them up? Dip them in water first? Any ideas are helpful.

[image: pinterest post] (https://www.pinterest.com/pin/11329436541148003/?lp=true)

Comment: Without knowing anything about lasagna, my guess would be that the Pinterest thing expects specifically *fresh* noodles, i.e. not dried, and it sounds like you bought dried noodles. Sorry!

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you bought and not what you were supposed to buy? I’m seconding Elenna in saying you bought the wrong stuff

Comment: @Elenna123 I would say that's an answer, not a comment. Besides the network having a [policy against that](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534/14685), I am pretty sure it will net you some upvotes :)

Comment: relevant: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28385/basic-process-for-making-lasagna

Comment: Was the Pinterest post about a specific product and brand? The one pictured? and is that what you purchased?

Comment: @rumtscho Yeah, I figured, just wasn't quite sure enough of myself. Feel free to delete the comment if you like, since it looks like Onyz already posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

It definitely seems like you were supposed to purchase *fresh* Lasagna noodles, as Elenna123 said in a comment. If the noodles are hard, they're not fresh. Fresh noodles would be pliable enough for you to fold them like dumplings, for example.

If you really wanted to make use of the dry lasagna you purchased, you could attempt to cook them (follow the instructions on the box) and then after a small amount of drying (maybe about 15 minutes in an oven at 200-250, if I had to guess?) attempt to prepare them using the egg brush and folding them. You would normally whisk the eggs and brush that on the edges, like you expected.

Hope this is helpful, but really, my best suggestion for what to do with the dry noodles is simply to make some normal pasta. Lasagna is pretty tasty, after all. :)